# Scroll management for LongListMultiSelector

Tags: scroll, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my WP8 application I use `LongListMultiSelector` and I would like to save it's scroll position when application is closed or tombstoned and then restore it when application is opened again. I will also need to scroll it programmatically to a specified item or specified position with animation when application is active.

The problem is that so far I can't find any methods on `LongListMultiSelector` that will allow me to scroll it with or without animation to a specified item or position. I also can't find methods that will allow me to get a list of all current items so I could choose of them to which one to scroll.

It can't be that scrolling is unmanageable on `LongListMultiSelector` so I'd like to get your advice on how I can get to this scroll functionality.

Comment: I don't have access to any code now, but the [ScrollTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.scrollto(v=vs.105).aspx) is not available? The LongListMultiSelector is an extension of the LongListSelector...

Comment: No, it's not. Not on my machine at least. I have a standard Visual Studio Express 2012 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LongListSelector is kind of a "smart" controls. It means it has very complex behaviour but if you need to change it - better you shouldn't...

You have two options:

1. Write your own behavior on top of the content of the LongListMultiSelector. It contains primitives:ScrollBox control inside it.
2. Use standard LongListSelector and implement native ScrollTo method and your own multiselection. Multiselection is a simple task, ScrollTo is quite tricky since you basically can't scroll to position, only to item.

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather go with first option if it can provide all the functionality I need (scrolling to an item rather than position is fine). How can I get to primitives:ScrollBox in LongListMultiSelector and where can I read about it? Google search only finds "ScrollBar" Class.

Comment: Also, under behavior do you mean C# custom behaviors as programming concept?

Comment: My mistake, it is primitives:ScrollBar. You can access it through LongListMultiSelector container as FrameworkElement by selecting a child with appropriate type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls Note than you can access it only when the list finished loading. Under behavior i mean simple your code to implement interaction, not c# concept.

Comment: BTW the first way may be more more complicated than the second.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to proceed with second option. Just tried a method from your link and `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)` returns 0. It's quite shocking actually that such an obvious funtionality is not included by default in `LongListMultiSelector`.

Comment: @Anton >VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent) returns 0. You shoud try to call this function inside Loaded event of LongListSelector. Otherwise it has not loaded yet and therefore has no child items.

Comment: Indeed you are right. It's working and I'm even able to reach to `LongListSelector` with it's `ScrollTo` function inside of `LongListMultiselector`. Still a lot is unclear but that's a topic for another question I guess.

Comment: @Anton you can write me on e-mail in the profile, I will give you some code for this task. Since I have already done this restore position task for my project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't see any e-mail in your profile, mine is balshoy.tone@gmail.com